# Python API for Elastic Search - How can we filter search results based on multiple fields?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying the below format but it is returning an empty dictionary.

```
result_dict = es.search(index="comp*", body={"from": 0, "size": 10000,"query": {
    "constant_score" : {
        "filter" : {
             "bool" : {
                "must" : [
                    { "term" : { "tags" :"prod" } }, 
                    {"term"  :{ "severity" :"INFO" }}
                    {"term"  :{ "service" :"abc-service" }}
                ]
            }
              }
                 }
                    } )
```

Comment: Could you share the mapping of tags, severity & service fields?

Comment: Post one sample document that you are expecting to return

Comment: @Developer there are 2 things here
1. You could use a bool query with a filter so that the query clauses inside the filter won't contribute to the score, instead of wrapping the entire query into a constant_score query
2. Please ensure that the mappings of tags, severity, service is of type keyword and not text. 
Can you please post the output of curl -k <es_url>/comp*/_mapping here so that i can see what's going on